# Windows mobile,change version number

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, mobile, cab

How can I set/change the version number of my builds in my windows mobile 6.1 professional application? I create a cab file, and I want to understnad the differnce between builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version number of the application is set in the AssemblyInfo file (you can move it, but that's the default location).  That number, however, is not used in the CAB file.  The CAB file containing an application has no versioning in and of itself.

**EDIT**
To check the version number, use something like this:

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Comment: Thanks! and how can I check the assembly version number from my mobile phone?